# Django Tutorial: Templates and Views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm in the process of completing the official Django tutorial and I'm stuck on part 3. Since templates are also used in the last part of part2, I will describe what I did:

Part 2 told me to "copy the template admin/base_site.html from within the default Django admin template directory in the source code of Django itself (django/contrib/admin/templates) into an admin subdirectory of whichever directory you're using in TEMPLATE_DIRS."

So I created a new directory "admin" that has the following relative path (note that where Django uses the directory name 'mysite', I use 'django_test' : /django_test/polls/templates/admin. I copied the base_site.html file into this directory.

When I render the file in my local browser, it says: `{% extends "admin/base.html" %} {% load i18n %} {% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'Django site admin' %}{% endblock %} {% block branding %}{% trans 'Django administration' %}{% endblock %} {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}`

Part 3 has me create an index.html file in a new subdirectory polls/index.html. But when I load this file in my web browser (using localhost server), I simply see the html code instead of a bulleted list (see below).

Note that I also edited TEMPLATE_DIRS in my settings.py file to tell Django that it can find index.html under /Users/myname/Sites/django_test/django_test/templates

Below I will paste the  code that my local server renders (instead of the bulleted list, which is what I want). Do you know why this code is being rendered, instead of the bulleted list?

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>

<body>
{% if latest_poll_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know whether I'm making a mistake in how I'm organizing the files. Might someone have an idea about what I'm doing wrong?

[image: files]

Comment: Exactly what address are you putting into your browser to view this?

Comment: Might be useful if you included your views.py code and the urls.py code.

Comment: I'm putting the following address into my browser:  file://localhost/Users/myname/Sites/django_test/django_test/templates/polls/index.html

Comment: My views.py code is: http://codepad.org/THXO1wuj and my urls.py code is http://codepad.org/pN8FlOBn

Answer (score 2):

As you say in your comment, you're putting the file path into your browser. Naturally, then, you're going to see the text of the template, because you are bypassing Django completely and getting the browser to load the unrendered template from disk.

As the tutorial describes, you need to ask Django to serve the template and render it, via its normal URL mechanism. In the earlier part of that section, you went to `localhost:8000/admin/` to see the admin site - this hasn't changed just because you've replaced a template. Go back to that address and you'll see your updated - and rendered - template.

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful. Now I'm still getting an error though:TemplateSyntaxError at /polls/
Could not parse the remainder: '<a href="http://poll.id/">poll.id</a>' from '<a href="http://poll.id/">poll.id</a>'  Do you know why that might be happening?

Comment: I'm getting the TemplateSyntaxError when I put the following into my browser: http://localhost:8000/polls/.You're right though, when I add /admin/, I get the admin view. I guess that's what I'm supposed to get. Thank you.

Comment: The template you've posted above wouldn't give that error. I suspect you haven't posted the actual code you have used - note for example that the version in the question has `poll.question` inside the `a` tags, but your error message is showing `poll.id` there. Please cut and paste the exact contents of the template.

Comment: Mmm, if by "template" you mean the view.py code, then this is the only code I have : http://codepad.org/1bRRqzX6. If you mean the html code in my index.html file, then it's <html><head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
{% if latest_poll_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>

Comment: Sorry, let me know if I should reformat this. BUt like I said before, I'm only getting the error message now if I open http://localhost:8000/polls/. Otherwise, if I write 'admin' between 8000 and polls (i.e. 80000/admin/polls/), the page renders. I'm not sure if that's what the tutorial meant to show me though.

Answer (score 0):

The django admin site is easy once you get the hang of it.

The steps to take are:

-Uncomment the django admin site in your urls.py

-Make the css available to the admin site by either copying the admin folder (inside django package) into the folder specified in STATIC_ROOT in your settings.py or making the diectory available on your PYTHONPATH

In other words, you dont need to create a template for the admin site. You will, however, need to create templates to access the views that you create in your project